# Difference b/w plugin based on name and plugin based on function

Tags: jquery

as i have just started developing plugins in jquery i am curious to know the difference between plugin based on name and plugin based on function and what is better approach to develop a plugin

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @elclanrs i am studying jquery plugin development in which author has explained above 2 ways of developing plugins but nothing written about the difference between two approaches and which to prefer

Comment: @Bipin can you link to the article, or give examples of both?

Comment: Do you mean var myfunc = function() vs function myfunc() ?

Comment: Well, excellent answerS here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plugin based on name also called method plugin and plugin based on function also called function plugin

1. Method plugins should always return the jQuery object (this, in the code),
   to allow for chainability.
2. Function plugins do not support chainability, Method plugins do support chainability.
3. Method plugins should always return the jQuery object (this, in the code),
   to allow for chainability.
4. Method plugins extend the jQuery.fn object, Function plugins directly extends the jQuery object.